# Working with multiple intents in application

Tags: android, android-intent

i have a problem in using intents
there are 5 activities in the application
the natural flow of passing intent extras is A-->B-->C-->D-->E

however depending on a condition , C may or may not be started
 when C is not started, i want to start D from B directly
this time D will require data from A and B

if C is started it adds some intent extra and starts D
(D needs extras from A,B and C)

currently i have 2 make 2 copies of D to receive intents like this

is there a way wherein i can have a single copy Of D, which wil start depending on whether it is instantiated by either B or C
or D should obtain that extra intent which is put by C?

i m a complete noob to android,any workaround or solutions welcome please..
thanks !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put an extra flag , to decide which activity is calling D. check this flag when you start the activity D and if you get call from C look for extras passed form C, otherwise ignore them.

in activity B.

Intent i = newIntent(context, D.class);
      i.putExtra("fromC", false);
      startActivity(i);

in activity C:

```
Intent i = newIntent(context, D.class);
  i.putExtra("fromC", true);
  // add more extras.
  startActivity(i);
```

in activity D:

```
boolean fromC = getIntent().getBooleanExtra("fromC");
  if (fromC) {
      // read extras that have been passed from C.
  }
```

HTH.

Comment: can u elaborate?
i know i cant start the same activity from 2 different activities
when i do getIntent() in D
it will give force close

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to make copy of Activity D.
When extras are not present in intent then null is returned so you have to just check where am i getting null or not.

Comment: but extras from A and B will still b there
when C is started, i want to add extra of C and then start D